# Trying to Find a Function whose Laplace Transform is $\frac{z}{z^3-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform

> I am trying to find a function whose Laplace transform is $$\mathcal{L}(f)(z)=\frac{z}{z^3-1}.$$

I first simplify$\mathcal{L}(f)(z)$ by solving for the cube roots of unity. Hence, $$\mathcal{L}(f)(z)=\frac{z}{(z-1)(z-w)(z-\overline{w})}, \ \ \text{where} \ \ w=-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.$$

Using a inversion formula, $$f(t)=\sum_{j=1}^{3}\text{Res}(\mathcal{L}(f)(z)e^{zt},z=a_j),$$ I compute $$\text{Res}(\mathcal{L}(f)(z)e^{zt},w)=\lim_{z\to w}\frac{e^{zt}}{(z-1)(z-\overline{w})}=\frac{e^{wt}}{(w-1)(w-\overline{w})}.$$
My question is, how do I simplify this? The result I have states $$\text{Res}(\mathcal{L}(f)(z)e^{zt},w)=\frac{e^{wt}w}{3w^2}=\frac{\overline{w}}{3}e^{wt}.$$ Expanding out the brackets seems too tedious. For instance, if it is given $$\mathcal{L}(g)(z)=\frac{1}{z^4+1},$$ it would take too long to simplify the expression for each residue. Is there another way?

Comment: Try partial fraction.

Comment: I initially thought of this, but I think this would only complicate things as further computation would be required

Comment: The answer given by Mathematica $-\frac{e^{-t}}{3}+\frac{e^{t/2} \sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} t}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{3} e^{t/2} \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} t}{2}\right)$ probably shows that partial fraction and residue method are the only ways.

Comment: Is there a way to simplify the expression that I have indicated, i.e. how does $$\frac{e^{wt}}{(w-1)(w-\overline{w})}=\frac{\overline{w}}{3}e^{wt}.$$

Comment: The problem with using partial fractions is determining the correct decomposition. I do not see this method being any easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like your method but in this case I prefer to choose partial fraction decomposition 
\begin{align}
\dfrac{z}{z^3-1}
&= \dfrac13\dfrac{1}{z-1}-\dfrac13\dfrac{z+\frac12}{z^2+z+1}-\dfrac13\dfrac{-\frac32}{z^2+z+1} \\
&= \dfrac13\dfrac{1}{z-1}-\dfrac13\dfrac{z+\frac12}{(z+\frac12)^2+\frac34}-\dfrac13\dfrac{-\frac32}{(z+\frac12)^2+\frac34} \\
&= \dfrac13\dfrac{1}{z-1}-\dfrac13\dfrac{(z+\frac12)}{(z+\frac12)^2+(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^2}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\dfrac{(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})}{(z+\frac12)^2+(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^2} 
\end{align}
then 
$${\cal L}^{-1}\left(\dfrac{s-c}{(s-c)^2+a^2}\right)=e^{ct}\cos at$$
$${\cal L}^{-1}\left(\dfrac{a}{(s-c)^2+a^2}\right)=e^{ct}\sin at$$
with $c=-\frac12$ and $a=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, then
$${\cal L}^{-1}\left(\dfrac{z}{z^3-1}\right)=\dfrac{1}{3}e^t-\dfrac{1}{3}e^{-t/2}\cos\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t\ +\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}e^{-t/2}\sin\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t$$

Comment: I like this approach. I did not consider using partial fractions at this point, rather I tried to use partial fractions for $$\frac{z}{(z-1)(z-w)(z-\overline{w})},$$ which was not pleasant. I will carry on from your work :) (I will mark as accepted answer once done) +1

Comment: Don't worry about accepting the answer, wait for people discuss about your method :)

Comment: For the case $\frac{1}{z^4+1}$,  would you suggest partial fractions too?

Comment: yes, $\dfrac{i}{2}(\dfrac{1}{z^2+i}-\dfrac{1}{z^2-i})$

Comment: Are you able to edit your answer such that it concludes the solution? I'm unsure of how to use the Laplace transform on $$-\dfrac13\dfrac{z+\frac12}{(z+\frac12)^2+\frac34}-\dfrac13\dfrac{-\frac32}{(z+\frac12)^2+\frac34}.$$ The first term is simple: $$\dfrac13\dfrac{1}{z-1}=\frac{1}{3}e^t.$$

Comment: Can I just ask, the formula $${\cal L}^{-1}\left(\dfrac{a}{(s-c)^2+a^2}\right),$$ is this a special case? The only identity I know is $$t^ke^{-at}\iff\frac{k!}{(z+a)^{k+1}}.$$

Comment: This called translation (I think), $${\cal L}\left(e^{ct}f(t)\right)=F(s-c)$$ so with factor $e^{ct}$ all $s$ in Laplace shift with $c$ value. then $${\cal L}^{-1}F(s-c)=e^{ct}f(t)$$

Comment: Can $c<0$? For instance, does $$\frac{1+z}{(1+z)^2+3}=e^{-t}\cos(\sqrt{3}t)?$$

Comment: yes, $c\in\mathbb{R}$.